# Changing a reactiveVar based on Jquery.validate() results in meteor.js

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery.validate() package in meteor.js to make sure that correct input is put into a form.

On submit, I am using a reactiveVar to change my view output.  How do I only change the reactiveVar if the validation tests are passed?

Looks like this:

thissite.js:

```
Template.inquiry.onCreated( function() {
    //toggles 'thank you' on inquiry template
    this.showForm = new ReactiveVar( true );
});

Template.inquiry.onRendered(function(){
    $('#request-form').validate();
});
```

inquiry.js

```
Template.inquiry.helpers({

  //toggles 'thank you' on inquiry template
  showForm: function () {
    return Template.instance().showForm.get();
  },

});

Template.inquiry.events({
  'click .submit': function(event, template) {
    template.showForm.set( false );
    Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
      template.showForm.set( true );
    }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
  },
});
```

inquiry.html:

```
<template name="inquiry">

{{#if showForm }}

<form class="request-form" id="request-form" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required />
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send Inquiry" />

{{else}}

Thank You message

{{/if}}

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    'click .submit': function(event, template) {

        var $form = template.$('.request-form');

        if ($form.valid()) {
            template.showForm.set( false );

            Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
              template.showForm.set( true );
            }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`Jquery.validate()` has callback option method `submitHandler`, you can read about it in the [validate plugin docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler).

```
Template.inquiry.onRendered(function(){
    $('#request-form').validate({
        submitHandler: function() {...}
    });
});
```